# @ViewChild value is not available in parent?

Tags: angular, angular8

**Parent** component is:

```
export class DictionaryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(ViewModeComponent)
  primarySampleComponent: ViewModeComponent;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log('Values on ngAfterViewInit():');
      console.log(this.primarySampleComponent.viewMode);

    }  

}
```

**Children** component is `ViewModeComponent`:

```
export class ViewModeComponent {

  public viewMode: mode = 'inline';
  public constructor(
  ) {}

  public switchMode(mode: mode) {
    this.viewMode = mode;
  }
}
```

Why after changing value this.viewMode in children component I don't receive it value in parent `ngAfterViewInit() {}`?

Console.log says nothing.

Angular version is 8

Comment: Then you should use an event emitter instead..!

Comment: How to justify this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `EventEmitter` to emit values from your child components

**parent.html**

```html
<ChildComponent (viewModeEvent)="handleViewModeChange($event)"></ChildCompoment>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
Import {..., Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

export class ViewModeComponent {

  @Output() viewModeEvent = new EventEmitter<mode>(); 
  public viewMode: mode = 'inline';

  public constructor(
  ) {}

  public switchMode(mode: mode) {
    this.viewModeEvent.emit(mode)
  }
}
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
handleViewModeChange(args: mode) {
  // gets called everytime there is a viewMode change emitted from child
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Observables

**in Service**

```
private viewMode = new BehaviorSubject(false); // create observable variable
checkMode = this.viewMode.asObservable();

changeMode(falg) {
    this.viewMode.next(falg);
}
```

**In Child Component :**

```
this.viewMode // local variable of Component

public switchMode(mode: mode) {
    this.viewMode = mode;
    this.service.changeMode(mode); // setting value to observable variable
}
```

**in Parent Component :**

```
this.viewMode // local variable of Component
this.service.checkMode.subscribe(response => this.viewMode = response); // get the value
```

Comment: What is it: `this.service.changeMenu(mode);`?

Comment: In this Service method, you are setting and getting values from the service scope variables

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using the `EventEmitter`. Just make an EventEmitter in the child component and pass the event to the parent component..!

**child.component.ts**

```
export class ChildComponnent implements OnInit {

  name: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => this.name.emit(new Date().toString()), 1000);
  }

}
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('appChild', { static: true }) appChild: ChildComponnent;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appChild.name.subscribe(console.log);
  }

}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-child #appChild></app-child>
{{(appChild.name | async) | json}}
```

You can see the live example in the stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-19v4pr)..!